# Why external ID removed in membership import in update mode?

Tags: civimember, import

During Membership import in update mode externalID available in civicrm 2.0 
and it seems that it is being removed in CiviCRM 4.6.7.

As I have a csv file to import membership with only externalID field in it.

What am I missing here ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that in CiviCRM, a contact may have more than one membership, so handling just external ID (or contact ID, at that rate) in update mode could be ambiguous.

I agree that it would be nice to take either of those, simply spitting out errors if it's actually a question of which membership to pick, but that hasn't been implemented.

To update memberships, do an export of existing memberships and get the **membership ID**, not the contact ID, for the ones you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

Civicrm Membership is using contact id in the latest version so the best way is to get all the contact Id corresponding the external Id - try importing it again

Comment: Thanks, Ramesh...But in my case I am getting a CSV file from other predefined system and not from CiviCRM..so I don't have contact id. I have only external id which map to CiviCRM member import....so any suggestion to make change in CiviCRM code base

Comment: any way if you are about to create membership you should have a contact already in the system right - then try to export all the contact record from the table and match external Id with the contact ID

Comment: Thanks, Ramesh...But I have multiple CSV File So how I can match them?

Comment: just import all the contact into any temp table, also the membership record into another table - and match all the external ID against contact and insert into the membership record and export to CSV

Comment: Yeah, Nice thought but Import Membership in update mode doesn't show Contact ID field in mapping...Any suggestion ??

Comment: if you are not getting the contact Id then you are doing something wrong i guess - are you trying to import in membership - > import memberships